# EF generates a unwanted SQL for nullable entity

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have an entity that uses another entity that can be null

```
class Parent 
{
   int? ChildId;
   Child Child;
}
class Child
{
   decimal Property;
}
```

I am trying to do a filter of the child property but it generates a strange SQL

```
Parents.Select(p => new { X = p.Child.Property <> 0 ? 1 : 0  })
```

But when I looked at the SQL it generated:

```
(([p.Child].[Property] <> 0.0) OR [p.Child].[Property] IS NULL).
```

The SQL that I want is to have

```
(([p.Child].[Property] <> 0.0) OR [p.Child].[Property] IS NOT NULL)
```

Can this be achieved without using `p.Child != null && p.Child.Property <> 0`. I tried this but it still adds the IS NULL condition.

Comment: EF6 or EF Core? If Core, what version?

Comment: EF core version 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by bug/defect in EF Core 2 which has been fixed in EF Core 3, because it doesn't happen there.

I've tried probably all possible syntax tricks, and it continues to insert that `OR IS NULL` condition, regardless of the `UseRelationalNulls` option.

At the end I was able to get the desired

```
[p].[ChildId1] IS NOT NULL AND ([p.Child].[Property] <> 0.0
```

translation by using the super counterintuitive expression

```
p.Child != null && !(p.Child.Property == 0)
```

(as you mentioned, the natural way of writing it

```
p.Child != null && p.Child.Property != 0
```

still includes `OR IS NULL` condition, although it has no effect on the result)

Comment: Thank you for investigating this. And for confirming that in EF 3 this does not happen.